# Compiling Cartographer CMake Error Could not find a package configuration ... cartographer_ros_msgsConfig.cmake

Tags: cmake, ros

Hi I followed the exact step by step procedure suggested at https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html to build the cartographer package, i've been trying to fix this error since two days, any help is very much appreciated. I did try individually building the packages they fail too.

```
[2/3] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer/package.xml
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//configuration_files
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//configuration_files/map_builder.lua
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//configuration_files/map_builder_server.lua
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//configuration_files/pose_graph.lua
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//configuration_files/trajectory_builder_3d.lua
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//configuration_files/trajectory_builder.lua
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//configuration_files/trajectory_builder_2d.lua
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//cmake/modules
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//cmake/modules/FindSphinx.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//cmake/modules/FindGMock.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//cmake/modules/FindEigen3.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//cmake/modules/FindLuaGoogle.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer//cmake/functions.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/cartographer_autogenerate_ground_truth
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/cartographer_compute_relations_metrics
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/cartographer_pbstream
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/cartographer_print_configuration
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/libcartographer.a
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/configuration_file_resolver.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/fixed_ratio_sampler.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/histogram.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/lua.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/lua_parameter_dictionary.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/math.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/port.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/task.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/thread_pool.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/time.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/ground_truth/autogenerate_ground_truth.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/ground_truth/relations_text_file.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/color.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/coloring_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/counting_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/draw_trajectories.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/file_writer.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/fixed_ratio_sampling_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/frame_id_filtering_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/hybrid_grid_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/image.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/intensity_to_color_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/min_max_range_filtering_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/null_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/outlier_removing_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/pcd_writing_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/ply_writing_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/points_batch.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/points_processor_pipeline_builder.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/probability_grid_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/proto_stream.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/proto_stream_deserializer.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/proto_stream_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/serialization_format_migration.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/submap_painter.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/vertical_range_filtering_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/xray_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/xyz_writing_points_processor.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/2d/grid_2d.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/2d/map_limits.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/2d/probability_grid.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/2d/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_2d.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/2d/submap_2d.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/2d/xy_index.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/3d/hybrid_grid.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/3d/range_data_inserter_3d.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/3d/submap_3d.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/detect_floors.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/grid_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/id.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/imu_tracker.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/map_builder.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/map_builder_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/pose_extrapolator.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/pose_extrapolator_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/pose_graph.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/pose_graph_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/pose_graph_trimmer.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/probability_values.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/range_data_inserter_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/submaps.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/trajectory_builder_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/trajectory_node.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/value_conversion_tables.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/metrics/counter.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/metrics/family_factory.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/metrics/gauge.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/metrics/histogram.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/metrics/register.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/collator_interface.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/compressed_point_cloud.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/data.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/fixed_frame_pose_data.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/imu_data.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/landmark_data.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/map_by_time.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/odometry_data.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/point_cloud.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/range_data.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/rangefinder_point.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/timed_point_cloud_data.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/transform/rigid_transform.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/transform/timestamped_transform.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/transform/transform.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/transform/transform_interpolation_buffer.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/io/fake_file_writer.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/transform/rigid_transform_test_helpers.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/common/proto/ceres_solver_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/ground_truth/proto/relations.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/cell_limits_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/connected_components.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/grid_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/grid_2d_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/hybrid_grid.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/local_trajectory_builder_options_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/local_trajectory_builder_options_3d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/map_builder_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/map_limits.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/motion_filter_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/normal_estimation_options_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/pose_extrapolator_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/pose_graph.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/pose_graph/constraint_builder_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/pose_graph/optimization_problem_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/pose_graph_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/probability_grid_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/range_data_inserter_options_3d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/scan_matching/ceres_scan_matcher_options_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/scan_matching/ceres_scan_matcher_options_3d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/scan_matching/fast_correlative_scan_matcher_options_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/scan_matching/fast_correlative_scan_matcher_options_3d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/scan_matching/real_time_correlative_scan_matcher_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/serialization.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/submap.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/submap_visualization.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/submaps_options_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/submaps_options_3d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_builder_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/trajectory_node_data.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/tsdf_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/mapping/proto/tsdf_range_data_inserter_options_2d.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/proto/adaptive_voxel_filter_options.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/sensor/proto/sensor.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/transform/proto/timestamped_transform.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/cartographer/transform/proto/transform.pb.h
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer/cmake/CartographerTargets.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer/cmake/CartographerTargets-release.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cartographer/cartographer-config.cmake
[1/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/WriteState.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse
[2/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapEntry.msg geometry_msgs/Pose:geometry_msgs/Quaternion:geometry_msgs/Point
[3/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/StatusResponse.msg
[4/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/BagfileProgress.msg
[5/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/HistogramBucket.msg
[6/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/SubmapQuery.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse:geometry_msgs/Pose:cartographer_ros_msgs/SubmapTexture:geometry_msgs/Quaternion:geometry_msgs/Point
[7/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapList.msg geometry_msgs/Pose:geometry_msgs/Point:cartographer_ros_msgs/SubmapEntry:geometry_msgs/Quaternion:std_msgs/Header
[8/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/Metric.msg cartographer_ros_msgs/HistogramBucket:cartographer_ros_msgs/MetricLabel
[9/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/LandmarkList.msg cartographer_ros_msgs/LandmarkEntry:geometry_msgs/Pose:geometry_msgs/Point:geometry_msgs/Quaternion:std_msgs/Header
[10/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/MetricFamily.msg cartographer_ros_msgs/HistogramBucket:cartographer_ros_msgs/Metric:cartographer_ros_msgs/MetricLabel
[11/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/ReadMetrics.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse:cartographer_ros_msgs/HistogramBucket:cartographer_ros_msgs/MetricFamily:cartographer_ros_msgs/MetricLabel:cartographer_ros_msgs/Metric
[12/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/GetTrajectoryStates.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse:cartographer_ros_msgs/TrajectoryStates:std_msgs/Header
[13/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/LandmarkEntry.msg geometry_msgs/Pose:geometry_msgs/Quaternion:geometry_msgs/Point
[14/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/StatusCode.msg
[15/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/MetricLabel.msg
[16/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/TrajectoryQuery.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse:geometry_msgs/Pose:std_msgs/Header:geometry_msgs/Point:geometry_msgs/PoseStamped:geometry_msgs/Quaternion
[17/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/TrajectoryStates.msg std_msgs/Header
[18/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/FinishTrajectory.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse
[19/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/SubmapTexture.msg geometry_msgs/Pose:geometry_msgs/Quaternion:geometry_msgs/Point
[20/20] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/StartTrajectory.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse:geometry_msgs/Pose:geometry_msgs/Quaternion:geometry_msgs/Point
[1/21] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/HistogramBucket.msg
[2/21] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/StatusResponse.msg
[3/21] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/WriteState.srv cartographer_ros_msgs/StatusResponse
[4/21] cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs && /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh /usr/bin/python2 /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/../../../lib/genmsg/genmsg_check_deps.py cartographer_ros_msgs Install the project...
all 21 packages install 
**clipped due to body limit**

-- Install configuration: "" cartographer_ros_msgs/package.xml
Base path: /catkin_ws
Source space: /catkin_ws/src
Build space: /catkin_ws/build_isolated
Devel space: /catkin_ws/devel_isolated
Install space: /catkin_ws/install_isolated
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~  traversing 4 packages in topological order:
~~  - cartographer (plain cmake)
~~  - cartographer_ros_msgs
~~  - cartographer_ros
~~  - cartographer_rviz
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

==> Processing plain cmake package: 'cartographer'
build.ninja exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> ninja build.ninja in '/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer/install'
ninja: no work to do.
==> ninja -j4 -l4 in '/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer/install'
==> ninja install in '/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer/install'
<== Finished processing package [1 of 4]: 'cartographer'

==> Processing catkin package: 'cartographer_ros_msgs'
==> Building with env: '/catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
build.ninja exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> ninja build.ninja in '/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs'
ninja: no work to do.
==> ninja -j4 -l4 in '/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs'
==> ninja install in '/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros_msgs'
<== Finished processing package [2 of 4]: 'cartographer_ros_msgs'

==> Processing catkin package: 'cartographer_ros'
==> Building with env: '/catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cartographer_ros -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/catkin_ws/install_isolated -G Ninja in '/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros'
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   iostreams
--   regex
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/bin/
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros/test_results
-- Found gmock: gmock and gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is off
-- Could NOT find cartographer_ros_msgs (missing: cartographer_ros_msgs_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'cartographer_ros_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "cartographer_ros_msgs" with any of the following names:

    cartographer_ros_msgsConfig.cmake
    cartographer_ros_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cartographer_ros_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "cartographer_ros_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
  above files.  If "cartographer_ros_msgs" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:59 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'cartographer_ros': 
  Command '['/catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cartographer_ros', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-G', 'Ninja']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /catkin_ws/build_isolated/cartographer_ros && /catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cartographer_ros -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/catkin_ws/install_isolated -G Ninja
```

> find /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/ -iname "cartographer_ros_msgs*"

````
```/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cartographer_ros_msgs
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/pkgconfig/cartographer_ros_msgs.pc
/opt/ros/melodic/share/gennodejs/ros/cartographer_ros_msgs
/opt/ros/melodic/share/common-lisp/ros/cartographer_ros_msgs
/opt/ros/melodic/share/common-lisp/ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/srv/cartographer_ros_msgs-srv.asd
/opt/ros/melodic/share/common-lisp/ros/cartographer_ros_msgs/msg/cartographer_ros_msgs-msg.asd
/opt/ros/melodic/share/roseus/ros/cartographer_ros_msgs
/opt/ros/melodic/share/cartographer_ros_msgs
/opt/ros/melodic/share/cartographer_ros_msgs/cmake/cartographer_ros_msgs-msg-paths.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/share/cartographer_ros_msgs/cmake/cartographer_ros_msgsConfig-version.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/share/cartographer_ros_msgs/cmake/cartographer_ros_msgsConfig.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/share/cartographer_ros_msgs/cmake/cartographer_ros_msgs-msg-extras.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/include/cartographer_ros_msgs
```
````

Comment: Do you have those message files installed on your system? What does `find /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/ -iname "cartographer_ros_msgs*"` give you?

Comment: Thank you BTables, I have edited the question, can you please check. I tried today and failed too.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because it cannot find the specific `cartographer_ros` message definitions when building to your local workspace. Seeing how it is actually installed inside `/opt/` this most likely means you're only sourcing one workspace when building. Before building make sure to run `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`. That will setup your environmental variables and cmake search path to see files installed in `/opt/ros/melodic`.

If for some reason that does not work you can see above where the desired `cmake` file is actually installed. You can manually set the search path for that package by typing this command before building:

`export cartographer_ros_msgs_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/share/cartographer_ros_msgs/cmake/`

Comment: Thank you, strangely this error did not occur once i upgraded from Ubuntu 16 -> 18, I'm still not sure why.